# how to troubleshoot a load data infile query

Tags: mysql, sql, load-data-infile

I have the following query...how would I go about troubleshooting why it is not loading any data (my connection to my db is fine).

```
$filename = "/data/101Phones-Product_Catalog_TXT.txt";

mysql_query('load data infile "'.$filename.'" into table CJProducts fields terminated by "\t" lines terminated by "\n" (PROGRAMNAME, PROGRAMNAME, CATALOGNAME, LASTUPDATED, NAME, KEYWORDS, DESCRIPTION, SKU, MANUFACTURER, MANUFACTURERID, UPC, ISBN, CURRENCY, SALEPRICE, PRICE, RETAILPRICE, FROMPRICE, BUYURL, IMPRESSIONURL, IMAGEURL, ADVERTISERCATEGORY, THIRDPARTYID, THIRDPARTYCATEGORY, AUTHOR, ARTIST, TITLE, PUBLISHER, LABEL, FORMAT, SPECIAL, GIFT, PROMOTIONALTEXT, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, OFFLINE, ONLINE, INSTOCK, CONDITION, WARRANTY, STANDARDSHIPPINGCOST)');
```

http://billsprice.com/1_800_FLORALS-Product_Catalog_1.txt

EDIT:

```
 mysql> load data infile "/data/101Phones-Product_Catalog_TXT.txt" into table CJProducts fields terminated by "\t" lines terminated by "\n" (`PROGRAMNAME`, `PROGRAMURL`, `CATALOGNAME`, `LASTUPDATED`, `NAME`, `KEYWORDS`, `DESCRIPTION`, `SKU`, `MANUFACTURER`, `MANUFACTURERID`, `UPC`, `ISBN`, `CURRENCY`, `SALEPRICE`, `PRICE`, `RETAILPRICE`, `FROMPRICE`, `BUYURL`, `IMPRESSIONURL`, `IMAGEUR`, `ADVERTISERCATEGORY`, `THIRDPARTYID`, `THIRDPARTYCATEGORY`, `AUTHOR`, `ARTIST`, `TITLE`, `PUBLISHER`, `LABEL`, `FORMAT`, `SPECIAL`, `GIFT`, `PROMOTIONALTEXT`, `STARTDATE`, `ENDDATE`, `OFFLINE`, `ONLINE`, `INSTOCK`, `CONDITION`, `WARRANTY`, `STANDARDSHIPPINGCOST` SHOW ERRORS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SHOW ERRORS` and `SHOW WARNINGS` to get explicit messages.

Alternatively, try to execute this request in the mysql console to get more information.

Try to check this answer too: [Can I detect and handle MySQL Warnings with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47589/can-i-detect-and-handle-mysql-warnings-with-php).

Also backquote your column names as, for example, `CONDITION` is a reserved keyword. Modify your query as below:

```
mysql_query('load data infile "'.$filename.'" into table CJProducts fields terminated by "\t" lines terminated by "\n" (`PROGRAMNAME`, `PROGRAMNAME`, `CATALOGNAME`, `LASTUPDATED`, `NAME`, `KEYWORDS`, `DESCRIPTION`, `SKU`, `MANUFACTURER`, `MANUFACTURERID`, `UPC`, `ISBN`, `CURRENCY`, `SALEPRICE`, `PRICE`, `RETAILPRICE`, `FROMPRICE`, `BUYURL`, `IMPRESSIONURL`, `IMAGEUR`, `ADVERTISERCATEGORY`, `THIRDPARTYID`, `THIRDPARTYCATEGORY`, `AUTHOR`, `ARTIST`, `TITLE`, `PUBLISHER`, `LABEL`, `FORMAT`, `SPECIAL`, `GIFT`, `PROMOTIONALTEXT`, `STARTDATE`, `ENDDATE`, `OFFLINE`, `ONLINE`, `INSTOCK`, `CONDITION`, `WARRANTY`, `STANDARDSHIPPINGCOST`)');
```

Finally, you have written `PROGRAMNAME` twice. Is that normal?

Comment: ok i added than at the end of mysql statement, nothing is returned. Thoughts?

Comment: I edited my answer and linked to another answer. By the way, could you edit your question to show a sample of your data file?

Comment: I get this back #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONDITION, WARRANTY, STANDARDSHIPPINGCOST) SHOW ERRORS and SHOW WARNINGS'' at line 1   I will add a sample file too.

Comment: You need to backquote reserved words. Modified my answer.

Comment: well i tried it on phpmyadmin...but the file isnt on that server. The database is on its own server (I am using amazons RDS)...so i think there is problems with the directory of the file and sql figuring out where that is at. Do you see what i mean?

Comment: Try to connect to the database with mysql CLI.

Comment: check out the above...i tried it through shell and it goes through but does load the file and even with show warnings it doesnt show anything