# INSERT IGNORE INTO - but what column is the cause?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

'INSERT IGNORE INTO', how would I get the column which causes the ignore (the column which is set to 'unique'/'primary') ?

Example of usage, I insert users to the table and it wont insert if the username or email is already inserted - I want to know whether it was the email or username (or both) which is already inserted so I can print an error message on the screen via javascript.

Ofcause, you might suggest me to use SELECT beforehand. However, by doing this I'd have to run 2 additional queries - I'm trying to keep the script as clean / quick as possible.

I know mysql_affected_rows() can tell me if it's inserted or not, but it doesn't return the columns which provented it from doing so.

I assume I could use mysql_error or something? I'm not sure since mysql_error only shows on an error - since I use 'IGNORE' it wont buffer an error.

---

Would @mysql_query('INSERT INTO ...') work if I parsed mysql_error or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your query, you can execute `SHOW WARNINGS` to see information about duplicate keys.

You can find an example of PHP code handling MySQL warnings in the answer to this question: [Can I detect and handle MySQL Warnings with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47589/can-i-detect-and-handle-mysql-warnings-with-php)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't give me any 'UNIQUE column' errors. I'll try turning the 'IGNORE' off.

Comment: Yes, it works when I turn off the ignore. However, it gives me "Duplicate entry 'test' for key 2" any ideas how to make it tell me what column it is or should I just work with if($key == '2') ?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think there's a way to make it show the name of the key.